# "no conversation" error and stopping the program in android

Tags: java, android

please see the following code. I analysed the following code and It does not seem to be have anything wrong in coding. But when I run the following code in an emulator, I get **no conversation** error.

**Draw.java**

```
public class Draw extends View {
    Paint paint;

    public Draw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected  void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawRect(50,30,100,120,paint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Draw draw;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle s){
        super.onCreate(s);
        relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
  draw = new Draw(this);
  relativeLayout.addView(draw,240,320);
        setContentView(relativeLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the code run in your device well?

Comment: What is the "no conversation" error? Post the stack trace through LogCat.

Comment: Ok. I will post the error information.But please test the above code in your device or an emulator and say the result for me.

Comment: No. Add the stack trace, your actual question with some context and **maybe** *someone* will answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install the android studio again. the code will work well.